# Find the Automorphism group of direct product of Z(mod m) & Z(mod n).

Tags: group-theory

Find the Automorphism group of direct product of $\mathbb{Z}(\operatorname{mod} m)$ and $\mathbb{Z}(\operatorname{mod} n)$.
We know Automorphism of direct product of $\mathbb{Z}(\operatorname{mod} p)$ and $\mathbb{Z}(\operatorname{mod} p)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}(\operatorname{mod} p))$. Then how to generalize it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a classical result by Shoda:

```
@article{shoda28,
author =       "Kenjiro Shoda",
title =        "{\"Uber die Automorphismen einer endlichen Abelschen Gruppe}",
journal =      "Mathematische Annalen",
volume =       100,
pages =        "674--686",
year =         1928
}
```

that describes the automorphism group of an abelian group. The paper is eminently readable (well, if you can read German...).

In short, his result says the following: First split up into powers of primes. Different Sylow subgroups are characteristic and the Automorphism group is simply the direct product of the automorphism groups of the Sylow subgroups. So without loss of generality, assume that $m=p^a$ and $n=p^b$ with $b\le a$ and generators $x$ (order $m$) and $y$ (order $n$).

If $a=b$ the automorphisms then can be described by an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix over $Z_{p^a}$.

If $a<b$, then $x$ needs to be mapped to $x^ey^f$ with $e$ coprime to $p$, and $y$ needs to be mapped to $y^kx^l$ with $k$ coprime to $p$, and $l$ a multiple of $p^{b-a}$.

It is not hard to see that these conditions are not just necessary (to preserve order), but also that each these ''matrices'' $e,f;k,l$ gives an automorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  one generalization is to the case where $(m,n)=1.$  And then by the Chinese remainder theorem,  we have a cyclic group $\Bbb Z_{mn}.$  The automorphism group of a cyclic group is well-known to be the "group of units of the *ring $\Bbb Z_n$*".  (It's also called the "multiplicative group modulo $n$".)  So $$\rm Aut(\Bbb Z_{mn})\cong \Bbb Z_{mn}^×.$$

Now note that this group of units will often not be cyclic.    But since the group of units functor respects products,  we can still compute this.  For example,  say $m=5,n=7.$  Then $$\rm Aut(\Bbb Z_5×\Bbb Z_7)\cong \rm Aut(\Bbb Z_{35})\cong \Bbb Z_{35}^×\cong \Bbb Z_7^××\Bbb Z_5^×\cong \Bbb Z_6×\Bbb Z_4.$$

(In fact,  the group of units $\Bbb Z_n^×$ is cyclic precisely when $n=1,2,4,p^\alpha $ or $2p^\alpha.$)

---

Next, if $(m,n)\neq1$, then the situation can be a bit more complicated. The group we're trying to find the automorphism group of is not cyclic anymore. You mentioned the case $m=n=p.$

More generally,  while we always have $$\rm Aut(\Bbb Z_m)×\rm Aut(\Bbb Z_n)\le\rm Aut (\Bbb Z_m×\Bbb Z_n),$$ we don't in general have equality.